# If you are ensuring a system is producing correct outputs based on inputs, what type of testing would you apply?

Tags: testing, system, cat, uat

If you are ensuring a system is producing correct outputs based on inputs, what type of testing would you apply?

For example, your business has a time sheet system. The only modifications you make to the system entails users must input their time on a daily basis, and that the system generated reports on a daily basis, rather than weekly?

Is it fair to say this would entail:

- System testing
- Acceptance testing
- (alternatively combined acceptance testing)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Checking for specific outputs, based only on the inputs, is known as black box testing. As in, you are testing only the results knowing nothing about the internals (your code is a black box that you cannot see inside).